# Printing initial page instead of range without the prefix using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am relatively new to biblatex but have some experience with latex. I want to print only the initial page instead of page range in bibliography and suppress the printing of prefix pp. as well.
I know similar questions have been asked but couldn't find a solution to the effect.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[
 backend=biber,
 style=numeric-comp,
 url=false, 
 eprint=false,
 date=year,
 doi=false,
 sorting=none
              ]{biblatex}
 \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Born_1926,
author = {Born, M.},
title = "{Zur Quantenmechanik der Sto{\ss}vorg{\"a}nge}",
journal = {Zeitschrift fur Physik},
 year = 1926,
month = dec,
volume = 37,
pages = {863-867},
  doi = {10.1007/BF01397477}
 }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

This is what I have now:
[image]
And This is what I want:
[image]

Comment: See also [Displaying only the starting page of a page range in bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33565/35864).

Comment: @moewe Thanks. Fixed the typo in MWE. Yes this question is very related but was only partially helpful. I couldn't guess the subtle difference that would have solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}
```